# ModalViewController in iOS8

Tags: ios8, modalviewcontroller

I am upgrading old code to latest iOS8, I see lots of this:

```
if (controller.modalViewController
  && controller.modalViewController.parentViewController == controller)

if(tabcontroller.modalViewController) ....
```

I see lots of documentation about how to present a modalViewController, but not for when its a property like above code. What's the equivalent of above code in iOS8?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, it says:

> modalViewController  (iOS 6.0) The controller for the active presented
>   view'that is, the view that is temporarily displayed on top of the
>   view managed by the receiver. (read-only)
>
> Deprecation Statement   Use presentedViewController instead.

That's probably a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this, I just wasn't sure if it was the right answer.